# Servlet can not see an attribute

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

in some.jsp i have this code:

```
<%
            ArrayList<Team> teams = Lists_DEO.getAllTeams();
            for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++){
                Team curr = teams.get(i);
                %>
                    <div class="team-item-box <% if (i%2 == 1) out.print("second");%>"> 
                        <a href="/FUF_League/UserGetTeam?teamID=<%=curr.getID()%>" class="left"><img src="<%= curr.getImageURL() %>" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="/FUF_League/UserGetTeam?teamID=<%=curr.getID()%>" class="watch-now"><%= curr.getName()%></a> 
                    </div>
                <%
            }
        %>
```

and it makes its job ... (I've checked with out.print and every single teamID has its unique value);

in UserGetTeam (servlet) I have this code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.print(request.getAttribute("teamID"));
    RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/UserPages/UserGetTeam.jsp");
    dispatch.forward(request, response);
}
```

and it prints out "null"...

what's the problem?
i'm working on github, on this project, this code was working several hours ago, but now it doesn't and nobody has changed/commited this particular servlet or jsp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are passing in the url is a parameter and not an attribute. Parameters and attributes are different

You should use

```
request.getParameter("teamID");
```

The difference is

1. `request.getAttribute()` returns an Object and `request.getParameter()` returns String
2. Generally, parameters are sent from client, i.e. jsp and attributes are set and used at server side, e.g. setting an attribute in the session and using it.